# "Excerpt" option in Redactor?

Tags: templating, custom-field, redactor

I love using the excerpt option in Wygwam (CKEditor). I've looked high and low but as of yet, have been unable to find a way to have an exceprt show short of having a whole second field. I have seen a custom Twig filter running around that would allow to show first paragraph (which I could modify to show whatever) but I like the ease of doing it straight in the WYSIWYG. Anyone have any options? (looking for a solution for a news roll page)

(First P Twig filter)
https://gist.github.com/james2doyle/6629712

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the Redactor's pagebreak plugin. Check [out the docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields#templating).

If activated in your Redactor config, you will have the option to insert page breaks to your content, via a new “Insert Page Break” toolbar button.

Now you can get the first "page" in your template:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog') %}
    <article>
        <h1><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h1>

        {{ entry.richTextFieldHandle.getPage(1) }}

        {% if entry.richTextFieldHandle.getTotalPages() > 1 %}
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading…</a>
        {% endif %}
    </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah, this is grand Victor, thank you. This achieves what I want on this scale, though if I were ever to have multi-page entries, it wouldn't work as well. For my current circumstances, will work great!

Comment: If you have multiple page articles you have three possibilities: (1) Ignore the first page and start the pagebreak at the second. (2) Write a simple redactor plugin which mimics the pagebreak functionality and call it excerpt. (3) Use a separate field for an excerpt.